# Cant mark minecaft as executeable in xubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu, permissions, java, minecraft

I cant mark minecraft as executeable, I try rightclicking minecraft and starting it up with java 7, but i need to mark it as executeable, If i go to "properties" and go to "Permissions" it does not have a checkbox where i can mark it, I have tried doing the command: "chmod a+x minecraft.jar" but it just says: "chmod: cannot access ‘minecraft.jar’: No such file or directory" How to i mark it?

Comment: are you sure you are in the right directory when trying to apply the chmod command? Could you show us the output of `ls`?

Comment: What is "ls", sorry i dont understand

Comment: when you where trying to execute `chmod a+x minecraft.jar` you were doing so in a terminal. Type `ls` to list the files in your directory to make sure you are in the correct location.

Comment: Ah, i saved minecraft.jar on my desktop, how to i get there?

Comment: The comment below should work for you. Type `cd Desktop` and then `chmod +x minecraft.jar`..

Comment: You can also try `java -jar Desktop/minecraft.jar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy. First, open a Terminal and navigate to the directory that Minecraft.jar is in by typing `cd /home/yourusername/Desktop` if it's on your Desktop. Then type `chmod +x Minecraft.jar`. You may have to change the Minecraft.jar part if you have changed the file name.

Comment: He said that this didn't work in the question.

Comment: No no, I just typed Chmod a+x minecraft.jar I did not type "cd /home/user/desktop ;) let me see if it works

Comment: Oh, i feel like a derp now, my system is installed in danish, so i had to type "cd /home/myusername/Skrivebord"

Comment: Ty! It worked!!